# How to join two 3D lines with a third line that connects to each with tangent arcs?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need help trying to find the equation of a 3rd line that connects two lines that are already defined in 3d space. The third line has to connect to the first two with "fillet"/tangent arcs, both of the same radius. See the picture for clarifications. I do NOT want the first two lines to change in any way. Their start and end points need to stay exactly where they are.

Knowns: Arc radius and all parameters of the two already defined lines...start and end points, start/end tangent.

[image: Two Lines Joined by a Third]

Comment: I can solve it in 2D, but the 3D version gives me headaches :)

Comment: At each junction, you have a 2-D problem. Just work in the plane defined by the pair of line segments, i.e., by their three endpoints.

Comment: Different comments.

1) A little precision about mathematical precise vocabulary : you work with **line segments** (not full lines which are infinite) 

2) Your issue has in general no solution with circular arcs unless  the line segments you want to connect are co-planar.      3) There are solutions using **helical** connecting arcs.

Comment: @amd I was also thinking of that, but I think that's not true for the endpoints, but only to their "extensions". Because the arcy head part would be out of the plane, so they wouldn't look at each other.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Concerning your 2): It may be that for too large $R$ there are no solutions of the given problem. But of course there may be circular solutions even if the two given carrying lines are nonplanar.

Comment: If the extensions of the lines are skew, then in general it’s going to be impossible to both join the endpoints with a circular arc and have a “smooth” transition between line segment and fillet, i.e., to have the tangents to the arc coincide with the line segments.

Comment: @Christian Blatter : As underlined by amd, what I had in mind is "smooth" connections.

Comment: @JeanMarie I believe there are solutions using circular arcs, i use it everyday in my software. I just don't have an equation to solve for the solutions, i use for loops and approximations to get to the final answer.

Comment: @amd See my answer above, there are solutions with smooth transitions. I "see" them everyday

Comment: @CrouchingKitten exactly!

Comment: @joshDsub Show me a circular arc that smoothly joins the segment from $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,0,0)$ with the segment from $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,1,1)$. One can certainly join any pair of end points with a circular arc, but not with one for which the extensions of both segments are tangent to the circle.

Comment: As you’ve presented it, the problem is overconstrained, even when restricted to 2D. Unless you know a priori that everything lines up nicely and all you want to do is to compute the arcs, having a fixed fillet radius requires that you be able to adjust the segment endpoints, but having fixed endpoints requires that you be able to adjust the radius (when a circular arc is possible in the first place). OTOH, with the assumption that everything’s lined up correctly, finding the center of the arc comes down to solving a system of three linear equations.

Comment: @amd I tried the example you wrote, and I think it can be done smoothly, see: https://imgur.com/FMGbbOP  The 2 circles doesn't need to be in the same plane with each other, they only need to be in the plane of the lines they connect. The only restriction is that they cannot be too close to each other (compared to the radius). Otherwise can one choose arbitrary extension sizes to control the radii.

Comment: Ah, ignore my previous comments—I was completely misreading the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_i$ $(1\leq i\leq 3)$ be the lines on which the segments $\ell_i$ are lying, and denote by $P_1$, $P_2$ the given endpoints of  $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$.  The line $g_1$ and the unknown line $g_3$ are tangents to some circle (of given radius $R$). They therefore are lying in the plane $\Pi_1$ of this circle, hence intersect in a point $Q_1\in g_1$ outside of the segment $\ell_1$. The distance $r_1:=|P_1Q_1|$ is unknown; it depends on $R$ and the *deflection angle* $\alpha_1$ at $Q_1$ between $g_1$ and $g_3$. This $\alpha_1$ is the angle of the circular arc to be drawn later. It is easy to see that
$$r_1=R\>\tan{\alpha_1\over2}\ .\tag{1}$$
[image]

In the same way we have between $g_2$ and $g_3$ the relation
$$r_2=R\>\tan{\alpha_2\over2}\ .\tag{2}$$
But we have to be aware that each of the angles $\alpha_i$ depends on both $r_i$ in a complicated way, independent of these conditions.

Therefore you have to do the following: Consider the $r_i$ as variables ("unknowns"), and compute the points $Q_i\in g_i$ $(1\leq i\leq2)$. If ${\bf e}_i$ is the unit vector giving the direction of $g_i$ then $${\bf q}_i={\bf p}_i+ r_i\>{\bf e_i}\qquad(1\leq i\leq 2)\ .$$
Since $g_3=Q_1\vee Q_2$ the direction vector of $g_3$ is
$${\bf e}_3={{\bf q}_2-{\bf q}_1\over|{\bf q}_2-{\bf q}_1|}\ .$$ 
This ${\bf e}_3$ will depend on $r_1$ and $r_2$.  Compute the angles $\alpha_1=\angle({\bf e}_1, {\bf e_3})$, resp., $\tan{\alpha_1\over2}$, using vector algebra on the ${\bf e}_j$. Similarly for $\alpha_2$. Then determine the $r_i$ from the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. When these equations are satisfied you can properly fill in  two circle arcs of radius $R$ beginning at $P_1$ and at $P_2$.

Comment: Just for clarification: the relationship between $\alpha_i$ and $r_i$ that is independent from (1) and (2) comes from calculating the angle between the line on the extension points and $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten: Yes. See my edit.

Comment: When I try to solve the problem with this method, I get a quite ugly system. The two line segments are between points $a_1$ and $a_2$, and for the other line between $b_1$ and $b_2$. The distances between the extension points and the ends of the segments are $d_a$ and $d_b$. The extension points are $e_a$ and $e_b$:
$$\bar{e}_a=\bar{a}_2+d_a\frac{\bar{a}_2-\bar{a}_1}{\lVert \bar{a}_2-\bar{a}_1 \rVert}$$
$$\bar{e}_b=\bar{b}_2+d_b\frac{\bar{b}_2-\bar{b}_1}{\lVert \bar{b}_2-\bar{b}_1 \rVert}$$ The equations are in the next comment.

Comment: The only unknowns are $d_a$ and $d_b$, but it would take ages to solve it: $$\frac{\text{2}\!\:d_a^2}{r^2+d_a^2}-1=\frac{\left( \bar{e}_b-\bar{e}_a \right) \cdot \left( \bar{a}_1-\bar{a}_2 \right)}{\lVert \bar{e}_b-\bar{e}_a \rVert \!\:\lVert \bar{a}_1-\bar{a}_2 \rVert}$$
$$\frac{\text{2}\!\:d_b^2}{r^2+d_b^2}-1=\frac{\left( \bar{e}_a-\bar{e}_b \right) \cdot \left( \bar{b}_1-\bar{b}_2 \right)}{\lVert \bar{e}_a-\bar{e}_b \rVert \!\:\lVert \bar{b}_1-\bar{b}_2 \rVert}$$

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Nonsense. All of that complicated-looking stuff on the right-hand side of each equation is constant. Give those two constants names, clear the denominators, and you’ve got a pair of simple-looking quadratic equations.

Comment: @amd $e_a$ and $e_b$ are functions of the unknowns. And there's even "length" operation on them. Might have a look with Wolfram Alpha because I'm curious :)

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Even so, they are simple linear functions of the $d$’s. After squaring to eliminate the square roots in the denominators you end up with a pair of polynomial equations. There are many several methods for solving those.

Comment: @amd okay, I'll give it a try, for the practice :)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thank you! I will give it a go sometime today hopefully

Comment: Would you be able to explain each step in "Therefore you have to do the following" with a little more detail? I am trying to set up the equations, but I don't think I understand what to do at each point you make. I want to get to where @CrouchingKitten got to, but on my own.

Comment: @joshDsub I basically converted the `tan` to `cos` with these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities
then also applied the formula for the double angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae
I can send you the details when I get home in a couple of hours. But TBH I think you could simplify this problem if the parameter wasn't the circle radius, but the extension length of the lines. And then use 3-D splines to connect them. (I bet you want to use it in 3-D graphics?)

Comment: @joshDsub oh I didn't know that it's not possible to send private message. But the only other thing I did in addition to the above mentioned is to express the cos(angle) between the lines prof. Blatter mentioned, using the dot product. You can see this on the right side of my equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition  (This is why I converted the tangent to cosine)

Comment: @CrouchingKitten But i have no clue what the extension line length should/will be, so how could i make that a parameter? The only two things that need to be fixed are the circle radius and the start/end points of the lines. Also, I still haven't had any time to work on it.

Comment: @joshDsub I meant to use fixed lengths. But I see that the rendering quality would be worse. I'm thinking about another solution, might have time for it on the weekend. Until then I have annotated the equations I made before (and renamed $d_a$/$d_b$ to x/y), see: https://i.imgur.com/s0hToOq.png

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Maybe i'm not following, but it's not a rendering issue, its a geometry issue. I need all the start/end tangents of each line and joining arc to be parallel. These lines represent a real physical object and to be manufactured to the design, they have to follow this rule (among others). Also, the original lines are "fixed" , L1 and L2 that is...or were you referring to the extension lines? I was planning on attempting to look at your correct solution/work this week, starting today. Should i wait for the other solution you are working on or?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Did you actually solve it? I've spent all day, i think i need to throw in the towel, it's above me :(

Comment: @joshDsub I was neither able to. And it seems that in Wolfram Alpha it's also complicated to express an equation with vectors. (I didn't have much time to check though) What seems to be doable is to just express the radii as a parameter of the extension lengths (and the points). Then use a numerical optimization algorithm, which doesn't require the gradient or the hessian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization), but only needs to substitute the parameters and calculate r. Then minimize on the difference to the desired radius. But I guess you did something similar already.